# What is the recommendation when there is no adequate solution to the issue?

Tags: java, try-catch, sonarqube

What is the proper treatment for this try and catch to treat issue? The `file.exists()` will never return an exception

```
public File getFile(File file) {
        if (file.exists()) {
            return file;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao obter arquivo.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'll delete that method all-together. Doesn't seem to serve any purpose.

Comment: Using try/catch will gracefully return an exception...

Comment: You're just wrapping the `file.exists()` method there. Rather you can call that directly, where you're calling `getFile()` method.

Comment: Don't use a `File` object. Instead use a `Path` object and the `Files` class. The `File` class shouldn't be used in this day and age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure that the file will **always** exist, and that completely grinding your application to a halt with a `RuntimeException` is the correct behaviour in the unlikely event that the file really doesn't exist, then this is acceptable.

Usually, however, a better approach would be to throw a different exception like `CustomFailureException` (or whatever you may want to call it), log to output why exactly the application has failed, and exit gracefully. Just in the off-chance that one day that file really doesn't exist for some reason, then you'll know right away what the problem is.